# Where to use MongoDB and where MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, database

I am thinking about using one of two databases - MySQL and MongoDB. I am planning to storing text and numeric data and I will building my app in RoR.

So I don't know, which database system could be better for this purpose - can you help me, please, under which criterium I will decide?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me cast this question within more general setting and into some historical perspective.

In the 60s they were asking whether to use hierarchical or network database

In the 70s the debate was relational against network

In the 80s Relational turned into SQL databases, so question mutated to SQL vs. network

In the 90s it was SQL against object databases

In 00s it was SQL against XML databases

Today we have SQL vs. NoSQL

Do you see a pattern here? Would you still bet some money onto SQL competitor, especially if it's nothing more than glorified hash table?

Answer (score 4):

I have used also MySQL and MongoDB with Mongoid in my projects, and I can say that if you want to keep binary data like images, mp3s and other stuff in your database so try Mongo, for other reasons you can use SQL databases. MongoDB has no structure - you processing the hash, so you can dynamicly add and remove keys/columns.
In your case I would use MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should base your decision on the purpose of your application. Do you want to search through your text data, how will you define keys. There is little use in going for MySQL if you have to request each record and scan it. Even if there is functionality to do text scans in MySQL (does it have that?) MongoDB will probably do the job more efficiently. The other way around, if you are not going to use MongoDB's strong points then you might as well go for MySQL.

Another factor might be the deadline for implementing something. If you need it fast, don't waste time on learning something new. If you have time to experiment, figure out the key features you will most likely rely upon in your application.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you need a hard structure you should use MySQL because it't its nature, but if you need something more dynamic, whith no structure at all (schema-less) you should use MongoDB, I've never use MongoDB but I know it's more object/document oriented.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you could provide some more detail. Would your data easily fit into a schema, or do you need the flexibility that a document store offers? What about auto-sharding, etc? Without more information, no one can give you advice that fits your needs. Lacking that, you can't hope for feedback any better than people's personal preferences, which is little more than a flamewar waiting to happen.